# What is the best practice to broadcast and receive connection change globally across the whole app?

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have this simple broadcast receiver which is watching data connection changes:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context mContext;
    private Boolean mIsConnectedToInternet;
    private enum AlarmTypes {ALARM_TYPE_REPEATED, ALARM_TYPE_UNIQUE}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            this.mContext = context;
            Logger.d("Connection changed!!!");
            triggerActionBasedOnTheConnectionType(isConnectedToInternet());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e("onReceive method cannot be processed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnectedToInternet() {
        mIsConnectedToInternet = false;
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm =
                    (ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            mIsConnectedToInternet = activeNetwork != null &&
                    activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e("onReceive method cannot be processed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIsConnectedToInternet;
    }


    public void triggerActionBasedOnTheConnectionType(Boolean mIsConnectedToInternet) {
        try{
            if(mIsConnectedToInternet == true) {
                Logger.d("Device is connected");
            }
            if(mIsConnectedToInternet == false) {
                Logger.d("Device is not connected");

            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Logger.e("triggerActionBasedOnTheConnectionType method cannot be processed");
        }

    }
}
```

I would like to display some notification bar under the action bar if the device is off-line in all views and globally to deactivate all buttons with some class.

How can I do it in the right way? Is there a library for this?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple connectivity change broadcast receiver

1. Register the broadcast receiver in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeBR">
      <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
      </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```

also define permissions to access network state and have internet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

2. Next, create the NetworkChangeBR.java file, with the following content

   ```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
      int status = getConnectivityStatus(context);
      if(status==0){
        // Offline
        // Display notification
        // Deactivate buttons
      }else{
        // Connected 
        // Also you can check for status==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI or status==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
      }

    }
   ```

where **getConnectivityStatus** function is defined as

```
// Method to get status of network
private int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null  && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Wifi");
            return ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
        }
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "MOBILE");
            return ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
        }
    }
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "Not Connected");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i know how to use it. I asked on how to broadcast connection state afzer the change globally to process UI changes (deactivate buttons, show message under the actionbar, etc)

Comment: i donot understand...once the change is detected by your broadcast receiver , you basically call a function to deactivate the buttons..that could be a static function or a singleton class.

Comment: if you are having issue regarding getting access to Ui elements , well one way could be to define your broadcast receiver inside your activity ..in that case you will have reference to your UI elements , and you can deactivate them as per my comment when offline..or show notification..